# How to start openOCD on ARM M1 MacBook

Tags: openocd, apple-silicon

I'm having a hard time getting openocd to start. I attached an `STM32F3 Discovery` board.
When I run `openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f3x.cfg` I get the following error:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: open failed
```

Any help on how to start `openOCD` is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the cable I used was just a power cable which didn't support data transmission.

With a proper mini USB cable that has all 4 lines it worked right away.